# Difference between Application.sum and Application.Sum in Excel 2007 VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am writing a macro in VBA to get the sum of the values of a range in Excel 2007. However, whenever I try to type the following code :

```
sum = Application.Sum(Range("C2:C19")
```

The editor turns it into :

```
sum = Application.sum(Range("C2:C19")
```

Since I was not sure of the difference between them I tried them out in the Immediate pane with the Print statement. The one with Application.sum gives me the wrong sum while the one with Application.Sum gives me the correct sum. But since the editor automatically changes Sum to sum, I am unable to proceed further. Can anyone please tell me what's going on over here?

Comment: Change your variable name from `sum` into, e.g. `mySum` and next try to type code again. Alternatively try to use `WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C2:C19"))`

Comment: I changed `sum` to `transSum`, but the problem persists. I need the sum in a variable, would a `WorksheetFunction.Sum()` accomplish this, I mean it adds functions to the worksheet, right?

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Sum()` and `Application.Sum()` work almost the same, they differ in the way you need to deal with when error is returned. Just try `WorksheetFunction.Sum()`.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying question of why the VBIDE changes "Sum" to "sum" has to do with the editor's auto-capitalization functionality. You declared a variable as "sum", which takes precedence over the built-in function when it comes to capitalization. If you declared your variable as "Sum", then you wouldn't see the change. In reality, Application.Sum and Application.sum are the same.

The issue you were running into was that you were using an existing function as a variable name. That's why it wouldn't work.